# Problem with overriding a plugin element when an Admin prefix is used in Cakephp 4

Tags: templates, plugins, cakephp-4.x

My App is both using prefix `Admin` and having a plugin `RubriquesManager`.

In the plugin `RubriquesManager` I have 2 elements `articles` for each side (front side and admin side) :

- `/plugins/RubriquesManager/templates/element/articles.php` displays articles for front side
- `/plugins/RubriquesManager/templates/Admin/element/articles.php` displays articles for admin side (with buttons for article editing, deleting, ...)

In order to override in my app the  front side element `articles` of plugin `RubriquesManager` I have created the file :

`/templates/plugin/RubriquesManager/element/articles.php`

The problem is that Cake is using this element both for overriding element `articles` for front side and also for admin side while I didn't create `/templates/plugin/RubriquesManager/Admin/element/articles.php` !...

I don't understand the point for Cake to act like that ? Is there a way to tell to Cake not to try to overide for admin side ?

Comment: Can't test it right now, but IIRC element lookup has a fallback order, first prefixed ones are looked up, then non-prefixed ones. I guess the point is to avoid unnecessary duplication, for example elements could easily be something that you'd want to share across all sorts of layouts and prefixes. So what you're seeing might actually be the expected behavior, unless maybe if you actually have an admin prefixed element in your plugin, and it is still being overridden by the non-prefixed app one. Not sure if that would be the correct/expected behavior.

Comment: @ndm I do have an admin prefixed element in my plugin (`/plugins/RubriquesManager/templates/Admin/element/articles.php`) and it is overridden by `/templates/plugin/RubriquesManager/element/articles.php` as I didn't create `/templates/plugin/RubriquesManager/Admin/element/articles.php`... Weird...

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess that is the expected behavior currently, as app override templates are tested first and follow the same fallback order. So it's 1. app prefix-element, 2. app element, 3. plugin prefix-element, 4. plugin element. I can see how that might feel counter intuitive, and one might expect a different order, like 1. app prefix-element, 2. plugin prefix-element 3. app element, 4 plugin element. Not sure about the possible implications of such an order though. You may want to open an issue over at GitHub, and see what others think about it.